# WooCommerce: Custom field (order comments) to confirmation email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates

I'm looking for a simple plugin that works like this:

View order: add text field (order comments)

Confirmation email template: get [order_comments] if exists

So far I've been able to find way too complex order tracking plugins or just adding the WC default comments (which I don't want to show, unless customer note). ACF could work but I'm hoping for a simpler option here.

Comment: https://remicorson.com/add-order-notes-to-woocommerce-completed-order-email/ Check this snippet

Comment: @mujuonly yeah I noticed it. I'd need to filter out only the customer notes (not all notes like payments)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php

$comments = wc_get_order_notes([ 'order_id' => $order->get_id(), 'type' => 'customer']);

foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo '<p>'.$comment->content.'</p>';
endforeach;

?>
```

Try this code - to print only customer notes.